# how can i find distinct field in mongodb through node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

look at the documents of my **imageDetails** collection:

```
> db.imageDetails.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a187f4f2d4b2817b8448e61"), "keyword" : "sachin", "name" : "sachin_1511554882309_1.jpg", "fullpath" : "Download/sachin_1511554882309_1.jpg" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a187f4f2d4b2817b8448e62"), "keyword" : "sachin", "name" : "sachin_1511554882317_2.jpg", "fullpath" : "Download/sachin_1511554882317_2.jpg" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a187f4f2d4b2817b8448e63"), "keyword" : "sachin", "name" : "sachin_1511554882319_3.jpg", "fullpath" : "Download/sachin_1511554882319_3.jpg" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a187f4f2d4b2817b8448e64"), "keyword" : "sachin", "name" : "sachin_1511554882319_4.jpg", "fullpath" : "Download/sachin_1511554882319_4.jpg" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a187f4f2d4b2817b8448e65"), "keyword" : "sachin", "name" : "sachin_1511554882320_5.jpg", "fullpath" : "Download/sachin_1511554882320_5.jpg" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a187f4f2d4b2817b8448e66"), "keyword" : "sachin", "name" : "sachin_1511554882320_6.jpg", "fullpath" : "Download/sachin_1511554882320_6.jpg" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a187f4f2d4b2817b8448e67"), "keyword" : "sachin", "name" : "sachin_1511554882320_7.jpg", "fullpath" : "Download/sachin_1511554882320_7.jpg" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a187f4f2d4b2817b8448e68"), "keyword" : "sachin", "name" : "sachin_1511554882320_8.jpg", "fullpath" : "Download/sachin_1511554882320_8.jpg" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a187f4f2d4b2817b8448e69"), "keyword" : "sachin", "name" : "sachin_1511554882320_9.jpg", "fullpath" : "Download/sachin_1511554882320_9.jpg" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a187f4f2d4b2817b8448e6a"), "keyword" : "sachin", "name" : "sachin_1511554882320_10.jpg", "fullpath" : "Download/sachin_1511554882320_10.jpg" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a187f4f2d4b2817b8448e6b"), "keyword" : "sachin", "name" : "sachin_1511554882321_11.jpg", "fullpath" : "Download/sachin_1511554882321_11.jpg" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a187f4f2d4b2817b8448e6c"), "keyword" : "sachin", "name" : "sachin_1511554882321_12.jpg", "fullpath" : "Download/sachin_1511554882321_12.jpg" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a187f4f2d4b2817b8448e6d"), "keyword" : "sachin", "name" : "sachin_1511554882321_13.jpg", "fullpath" : "Download/sachin_1511554882321_13.jpg" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a187f4f2d4b2817b8448e6e"), "keyword" : "sachin", "name" : "sachin_1511554882321_14.jpg", "fullpath" : "Download/sachin_1511554882321_14.jpg" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a187f4f2d4b2817b8448e6f"), "keyword" : "sachin", "name" : "sachin_1511554882322_15.jpg", "fullpath" : "Download/sachin_1511554882322_15.jpg" }
>
```

I want the distinct values of the field **'keyword'** in nodejs as replacement in mongodb like:

```
> db.imageDetails.distinct('keyword');
[ "sachin" ]
```

I tried but didn't find any efficient way in node js mongodb module, so please suggest any method to do so if there is option around aggregation or something more effecient. I am stuck:

```
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    if (err)
    throw err;
    var cursor = db.collection(collectionName).find(findQuery);
    cursor.each(function(err, doc)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call [`distinct`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#distinct) on your collection. Here's an example:

```
db.collection(collectionName).distinct('keyword', function(err, docs) {
  // ...
});
```

Note that `distinct` does not return a [`Cursor`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Cursor.html). You can either use the callback approach as I've shown above or use a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), which can be achieved by not providing a callback. e.g.:

```
db.collection(collectionName).distinct('keyword')
    .then(docs => {
        // ...
    });
```

Comment: as distinct does not return a cursor, does that mean that if we use a distinct we will be forced to load the whole result into memory and not be able to load only the current row like we can do with the cursor object?